# Json Object to Form Fields

Tags: c#, json, razor

I have a json object which I store in a database table. The object changes from time to time with respect to nested objects, field names, etc. I would like to create a simple form editor in C#/Razor which dynamically reads the json object and creates a series of text fields.

I'm sure someone within this forum has solved this already. Anyone have any code I can use to get started or know of any shortcuts I might pursue?

Comment: this question is a bit too broad, rather try and have a go at the code solution yourself, then share it with any questions that come up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998832/gui-based-or-web-based-json-editor-that-works-like-property-explorer

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for: [how to create a html form using a JSON definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508871/how-to-create-a-html-form-using-a-json-definition)

Thanks for all the direction and help.