# HTML/Bootstrap form with Json API

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, api, forms

I want to create a simple HTML form (ideally using bootstrap).

On this form some input elements are filled by the user(which is simple!) but I also need to call an API with json data to fill a drop down box. like list of countries,etc.

How can I implement API into a form?

thanks

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>My form</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Article on Banking,etc." class="input-medium">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="Article Type">Article Type</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="Article Type" name="Article Type" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>ashkanarvaneh.co.uk/test/api.json</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="summary">Summary</label>
  <div class="controls">                     
    <textarea id="summary" name="summary">Enthusiastically strategize superior infomediaries after clicks-and-mortar process improvements. Appropriately incubate stand-alone methodologies vis-a-vis pandemic potentialities. Authoritatively build.</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="submit">Submit</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @Hassan I've added the code, basically I want the "article type" gets uses the API and get data from json document.

Comment: from where you will get json data? `http://publicapidev.chambersandpartners.com/api/taggedlocations` is not resolving to me.

Comment: @Hassan I've updated the link so anyone can view it. ashkanarvaneh.co.uk/test/api.json

Comment: http://php.net/curl & http://php.net/json_decode are your starting points. As it stands, your question is rather broad though.

Comment: @Ash I have added an answer. Please try it.

Answer (score -1):

Try Example

```
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="Article Type">Article Type</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="Article Type" name="Article Type" class="input-xlarge">
    <?php
        $countries = file_get_contents("http://ashkanarvaneh.co.uk/test/api.json");
        $countries = json_decode($countries, true);
        foreach($countries as $country)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$country['Id']."'>".$country['Description']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
      <!--<option>http://publicapidev.chambersandpartners.com/api/taggedlocations</option>-->
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note** The above code is tested & works fine.

Comment: I tried the code but the Article type is empty. I didn't vote you down though. Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Also would it be possible to use javascript lib as I'm more comfortable with that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508871/how-to-create-a-html-form-using-a-json-definition